# How I can extract parameters from xml?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

How I can extract value `Total topics`?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<command param = "Total topics" > Check title
</command> 
</config>
```

I know that for extracting value of `Check title` I need such code:

```
XPathExpression  expr = xpath.compile("//command/text()");
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Help me with param, please.

Comment: Just commenting here, there are many many XML Processing solutions out there available for Java. You arent limited only to XPath. Simple XML, and SAX are alternatives, along with many more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XPathExpression  expr = xpath.compile("//command[@param]/text()");
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

I've not compiled it but to select an attribute you'll need to used `@attributeName` after the node is selected.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `@` for attribute? Try with

```
XPathExpression  expr = xpath.compile("//command/@param");
```